# Combining :has with :not

Tags: css

I wish to add the following properties:

```
    display: grid;
    grid-column-gap: 20px;
    grid-row-gap: 20px;
```

to my class: `.simple-checkbox-options`

Providing it **doesn't** have a parent class called `.modal`.

I've tried the following:

```
.simple-checkbox-options{

    :has(.modal:not) & {
        display: grid;
        grid-column-gap: 20px;
        grid-row-gap: 20px;
    }
}
```

But it's not working. Any ideas?

Comment: I believe the code should be:   :has(:not(.modal))

Comment: @nourhomsi thanks I just tried that but it applied it for all scenerios

Comment: CSS selector `:has()` is not supported by all browsers, and it's not part of the official CSS specification. A better approach would be to use a more widely supported selector, such as `:not`.

You can try something like that:

```
.simple-checkbox-options:not(.modal) {
    display: grid;
    grid-column-gap: 20px;
    grid-row-gap: 20px;
}
```

This selector matches all elements with a class of `.simple-checkbox-options` that do not also have a class of `.modal`.


I cannot post it because i have to wait 30 minutes. Sorry the formatting

Comment: @baggiogiacomo thanks for your answer. :has is now supported by around 80% of browsers so I'm happy to use it. With your approach I'd have to ensure that the .modal class is also on the same div as .simple-checkbox-options which I can't do in my circumstances.

Comment: oh, 80%? I thought it was less; good to know!
oh yeah, in my case .modal have to be in the same div as .simple-checkbox-options. Sorry about that :(